# How to use the QOpenGLWidget object?

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget

I created a form for the application in Qt Designer and placed a *QOpenGLWidget* in it and got an **openGLWidget** object, but now I can't figure out how to draw with this object.
I will not be able to inherit from the object to write code inside its methods and other things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to inherit from it. You just have to use the [widget promotion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) mechanism in Qt Designer to promote your new `QOpenGLWidget` to your derived type.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions - you can of course create a derived class and use it in a `.ui` form file. But there's another complementary approach: create a class derived from `QObject` and install it as an event filter for the widget. In the reimplementation of `filterEvent` method of that class, you can catch the paint events and other relevant events and act on them.

Comment: This approach is lower-level: you'll have to do all the `QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent()` and other special actions yourself, instead of simply implementing `QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()` et al.